# When a politician stresses a particular issue (corruption, poverty, illegal immigration, and so forth), what do you call it?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When a politician stresses a particular issue (corruption, poverty, illegal immigration, and so forth), what do you call it? I considered 'talking point', 'selling point', 'agenda', but none of them seems to fit. For example

> Racial inequality has become the candidate's prime _________ during the congressional campaign.

I guess you could say 'point of agenda', but I don't like it. It's like I forgot some natural way of saying it.

Comment: [stresses out?? Nyet, no] You mean stresses an issue.

Comment: @Lambie Ok 4 more to go...

Comment: Politicians (in the US) run on political platforms. platforms are divided into planks. However, I'd use **prime focus** in that sentence....

Comment: Like Lambie, I would use 'focus' in your sentence.

Comment: @Void Is there a more specific word/phrase? I like 'platform'. Maybe, it's what I tried to remember in the first place

Comment: @Sergey: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a word you already mentioned: *issue*. That's a word with many (related) meanings, but the widespread use of terms like [single-issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-issue_politics) in politics makes it a natural choice here.